# How to open/install another APK file from inside React Native App built using expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have an android application built using expo (Managed Flow). I am trying to install/open a downloaded apk file from inside the application without success.

```
const fileUri = ...        
FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(fileUri).then(cUri => {
  console.log(cUri);
  IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', {
    data: cUri,
    flags: 1,
    type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
  });
});
```

I also tried:

```
const fileUri = ...
Linking.openURL(fileUri);
```

I need help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever manage to do it in expo?